# Minimizing scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf with respect to covariance

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, scipy, normal-distribution

I have a python script where I compute the value of a normal log-likelihood function for a sample of bivariate data using scipy's `multivariate_normal.log_pdf`. I am assuming the values of the sample means and variances, leaving only the sample correlation between the variables as the unknown,

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from scipy.optimize import minimize

VAR_X = 0.4
VAR_Y = 0.32
MEAN_X = 1
MEAN_Y = 1.2

def log_likelihood_function(x, data):
    log_likelihood = 0
    sigma = [ [VAR_X, x[0]], [x[0], VAR_Y] ]
    mu = [ MEAN_X, MEAN_Y ]
    for point in data:
        log_likelihood += multivariate_normal.logpdf(x=point, mean=mu, cov=sigma)
    return log_likelihood

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_data = [ [1.1, 2.0], [1.2, 1.9], [0.8, 0.2], [0.7, 1.3] ]
    
    guess = [ 0 ] 

    # maximize log-likelihood by minimizing the negative 
    likelihood = lambda x: (-1)*log_likelihood_function(x, some_data)
    
    result = minimize(fun = likelihood, x0 = guess, options = {'disp': True}, method="SLSQP")

    print(result)
```

No matter what I set as my guess, this script reliably throws a ValueError,

`ValueError: the input matrix must be positive semidefinite`

Now, the problem, by my estimation, seems to be `scipy.optimize.minimize` is guessing values that create a covariance matrix that is not positive definite. So I need a way to make sure the minimization algorithm throws away values that are outside the domain of the problem. I thought to add a constraint to the minimize call,

```
## make the determinant always positive
def positive_definite_constraint(x):
    return VAR_X*VAR_Y - x*x
```

Which is basically the [Slyvester Criteron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) for the covariance matrix and would ensure the matrix is positive definite (since we know the variance is always positiv, that condition doesn't need checked) But it seems like `scipy.optimize.minimize` evaluates the objective function before it determines if the constraints are satisfied (which seems like a design flaw; wouldn't it be faster to search for a solution in a restricted domain, instead of searching all possible solutions and then determining if the constraints are satisfied? I might be mistaken about the order of evaluation, though.)

I am not sure how to proceed. I realize I am stretching the purpose of `scipy.optimize` here a bit by parameterizing the covariance matrix and then minimizing with respect to that parameterization, and I know there are better ways to calculate the correlation for a normal sample, but I am interested in this problem because of its generalization to distributions that are not normal.

Any suggestions? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that your definiteness constraint reduces to a simple bound on the optimization variable, i.e. `-∞ <= x[0] <= VAR_X*VAR_Y`. Variable bounds are better handled internally than the more general constraints, so I'd recommend something like this:

```py
bounds = [(None, VAR_X*VAR_Y)]
res = minimize(fun = likelihood, x0 = guess, bounds=bounds, options = {'disp': True}, method="SLSQP")
```

This gives me:

```
     fun: 6.610504611834715
     jac: array([-0.0063166])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 9
     nit: 4
    njev: 4
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.12090069])
```

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm. Do you know if I am correct about the order of evaluation between the objective function and constraint?

Comment: @GrantMoore Yes, this is true for the SLSQP method, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/69ac1be8e0ad82b250ab50fa355de1312c6da428/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py#L428).